# NoMethodError in Insurances#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a second pair of eyes. I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

I created a new scaffold `rails generate scaffold Insurance string:name` followed by a `rake db:migrate`. However, when I go to the newly created page and select "New Insurance" I get the following error message.

*NoMethodError in Insurances#new Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/insurances/_form.html.erb where line #5 raised:
undefined method `insurance' for # Extracted source (around line #5):*

```
<div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :insurance %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :insurance, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

I'm sure it's something easy I just don't see it.

Insurance controller:

```
class InsurancesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_insurance, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @insurances = Insurance.all
    respond_with(@insurances)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@insurance)
  end

  def new
    @insurance = Insurance.new
    respond_with(@insurance)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @insurance = Insurance.new(insurance_params)
    @insurance.save
    respond_with(@insurance)
  end

  def update
    @insurance.update(insurance_params)
    respond_with(@insurance)
  end

  def destroy
    @insurance.destroy
    respond_with(@insurance)
  end

  private
    def set_insurance
      @insurance = Insurance.find(params[:id])
    end

    def insurance_params
      params.require(:insurance).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have `insurance` within whitelisted attributes (in `insurance_params`) and most likely you did not define such field in database (and why would you define an attribute identical to model name? :)),

So the following raises an error:

```
      <%= f.label :insurance %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :insurance, class: "form-control" %>
```

What you probably want is

```
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: @Andrey-denineko that seems to fix my problem. After reviewing my code a little more, I was able to see the problem. Thanks.